# Is is possible to have a IAM identity provider OIDC where the provider url is only accessible from my VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm getting the following error when using `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`

```
An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Couldn't retrieve verification key from your identity provider,  please reference AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity documentation for requirements
```

I found the [AWS support Article : How can I resolve the AWS STS AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity API call error "InvalidIdentityToken"](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-sts-invalididentitytoken/)? where it does state

> This error can occur if:
>
> - The .well_known URL and jwks_uri of the identity provider (IdP) are inaccessible from the public internet.

which is indeed my case since I'm using a private GitLab instance (not reachable from the public internet). The idea is to use the GitLab `$CI_JOB_JWT_V2` to `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` to avoid having long term credentials as GitLab CI/CD variables (see [Configure OpenID Connect in AWS to retrieve temporary credentials](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/aws/#add-the-identity-provider)). But it doesn't work because I can't add the GitLab instance as IAM identity provider since it's not public.

Is there any way to tell STS to contact the `https://xxxxx/.well-known/openid-configuration` via my VPC instead?

Comment: Same issue when using OIDC with Bitbucket pipelines and AWS. It seems that Bitbucket has the jwks.json file at a different address: 
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/workspaces/WORKSPACE_ID/pipelines-config/identity/oidc/keys.json

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: There is no solution other that exposing the `.well-known/openid-configuratio` publicly. Alternatively you can explor IAM Roles Anywhere that use PKI certificates instead of OIDC

Comment: Hi there, may I just check if there was ever a solution to this issue?