# Can you connect AWS IAM OIDC to a private External Identity Provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, openid-connect

I have a private identity provider (`gitlab.company.com`) that I would like to connect to my AWS account via [AWS IAM OIDC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html). `gitlab.company.com` is not publicly accessible to the internet. I am having issues connecting to (specifically, thumbprinting) our Gitlab instance from AWS. I can't find any actual AWS documentation on the issue.

I am looking for documentation or some other proof/evidence that there is an issue with private identity providers and AWS IAM OIDC. There are many blog posts and questions I've linked below saying that private identity providers are not supported but I can't find any official AWS documentation on the issue.

**Related Findings**

https://repost.aws/questions/QUKcB6zxUDR_a4vBnq3QRQDg/allow-communication-between-ec2-instances-running-under-different-aws-accounts

[Is is possible to have a IAM identity provider OIDC where the provider url is only accessible from my VPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74704431)

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/iam-sts-invalididentitytoken

https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1909

I tried creating an IAM identity provider according to the official AWS docs and official gitlab docs.

I expect AWS IAM OIDC to be able to thumbprint my private gitlab instance's IdP.

Actual Behavior: AWS IAM OIDC cannot connect to my gitlab instance.

Comment: Hi there, did you manage to get a solution for this?

Comment: We did not find a solution. We were brainstorming a way to allow AWS access through the firewall or trying to route the AWS IAM OIDC internally somehow. We ended up moving onto other things.